# White padding/margin on right side in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm struggling with this website I made using webflow.io

It displays perfectly on desktop, but on mobile I get a white margin or padding on the right side that completely damages the site. I've tried to debug the code but can't find the culprit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be coming from the "Describe your app" section image sliding in from the right.

Adding overflow:hidden to the parent element  should fix this or work on making the image absolute.